# Generating OVH SHA1 signature

Tags: delphi, sha1, delphi-10.4-sydney, ovh

I'm trying to utilize the OVH API in Delphi using the REST client. For this OVH requires me to generate a [signature, but their documentation](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/api/first-steps-with-ovh-api/#first-api-usage) does not provide much info on this other than:

```
"$1$" + SHA1_HEX(AS+"+"+CK+"+"+METHOD+"+"+QUERY+"+"+BODY+"+"+TSTAMP)
```

They do provide thin wrappers for other languages so I thought I could take a look at those and try to replicate it. I found the following for [generating the signature in C#](https://github.com/ovh/csharp-ovh/blob/master/csharp-ovh/Client/Client.cs#L228) and have extracted the function to be used in a test application.

Test app C# code:

```cs
textBox1.Text = GenerateSignature("appSecret", "consKey", 123456789, "PUT", "/path/to/api", "TEST DATA");
```

The C# result is:

> $1$8336ecc5d03640b976e0b3ba005234a3046ab695

I attempted the rewrite the function in Delphi and came up with the following function:

```pascal
function GenerateSignature(const appSecret, consKey: string;
  const currentTimeStamp: LongInt; const method, target: string;
  const data: string = ''): string;
begin
  var
  toSign := string.Join('+', [appSecret, consKey, method, target, data,
    currentTimeStamp]);

  var
  binaryHash := THashSHA1.GetHashBytes(toSign);

  var
  signature := '';
  for var byte in binaryHash do
  begin
    signature := signature + byte.ToHexString.ToLower;
  end;

  Result := '$1$' + signature;
end;
```

And to test it:

```pascal
procedure Main;
const
  APP_SECRET = 'appSecret';
  CONSUMER_KEY = 'consKey';
  method = 'PUT';
  target = '/path/to/api';
  data = 'TEST DATA';
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = 123456789;
begin
  Writeln(GenerateSignature(APP_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    method, data));
end;
```

Both test applications in C# and in Delphi use the same data but produce different outputs. My expected output is:

> $1$8336ecc5d03640b976e0b3ba005234a3046ab695

But I end up getting the following output from delphi:

> $1$d99fd5086853e388056d6fe37a9e2d0723de151b

I do not know C# very well but it seems to get the hashbytes then convert it to hex and stitch it together. How can I modify the Delphi function I wrote so that I can get my expected result?

Comment: You overlooked `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSign)` - are you sure your String consists of bytes in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @AmigoJack I just attempted `var
  utfEncoded := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSign);` and ended up getting the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the last parameter being optional you didn't notice (because no compiler error/warning) that you actually missed one parameter when calling/testing your function, resulting in a text of
`'appSecret+consKey+PUT+TEST DATA++123456789'` to be hashed. Which is indeed

> d99fd5086853e388056d6fe37a9e2d0723de151b

Let me reformat your test to make it more obvious:

```delphi
const
  APP_SECRET = 'appSecret';
  CONSUMER_KEY = 'consKey';
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = 123456789;
  method = 'PUT';
  target = '/path/to/api';  // Where is this used?
  data = 'TEST DATA';
begin
  GenerateSignature
  ( APP_SECRET
  , CONSUMER_KEY
  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  , method
  // Forgotten parameter
  , data  // becomes "target"
  );
end;
```

Consider making `const data: string = ''` mandatory, too, instead of optional.